# How to add inline Models in admin Interface [Django]

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to add an inline model to a `Post` model. As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline) says, i am trying to do something like:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

class Post(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Images = models.ForeignKey(images)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

class ModelInlinePost(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.images

class ModelPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    view_on_site = False
    inlines = [PythonInlineAdmin,]
```

When i try execute any command with `manage.py`. It throws back this error:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
 <class 'home.admin.ModelInlinePost'>: (admin.E202) 'home.Post' has no ForeignKey to 'home.images'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all posts with no images. The code below works for me:-

Models

```
class Image(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

class Post(models.Model):
  image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Admin

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
```